# Variant of dominated convergence theorem for changing sequence of spaces

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I'm wondering if there exists some variant of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, which applies to a sequence of functions that is defined over a **changing sequence of spaces**.
In particular, I'm interested in the following examle.

Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots$, be a sequence of functions, such that $f_d:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $d\in\mathbb{N}^*$.
Denote by $\cdot^{(d)}$ the restriction of a sequence to its first $d$ elements.
Suppose for every sequence of reals $x=x_1,x_2,\ldots$, it holds that
$$
    \lim_{d\rightarrow\infty}f_d\left(x^{(d)}\right)=0,
$$
and that there exists a sequence of functions $g_1,g_2,\ldots$, with $g_d:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $M>0$, such that for all $d\in\mathbb{N}^*$
$$
    \left|f_d\left(x^{d}\right)\right|\leq g_d\mbox{ and }  \int_{x^{(d)}\in\mathbb{R}^d}g_d\left(x^{(d)}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{(d)}\leq M.
$$
Can we show that
$$
    \lim_{d\rightarrow\infty}\int_{x^{(d)}\in\mathbb{R}^d}f_d\left(x^{(d)}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{(d)}=0?
$$
If false, can we add extra conditions for this to hold (e.g., the functions are continuous and/or or restricted to $[a,b]^d$, ...)?

I would really appreciate some hints or references.

Comment: Your "domination" condition just says $\int_{\mathbb R^d} |f_d| \le M$, because you can take $g_d = |f_d|$.  It's not true, even for functions of the form 
$ f_d(x^d) = h_d(x_1) I_{(x_2,\ldots , x_d) \in [0,1]^{d-1}}$.

Comment: Okay I see, thank you!